# Appropriate verb for a child who firmly grabs something

Tags: american-english, british-english

I'm trying to figure out what could be the most appropriate verb to use to describe a child grabbing firmly something in a shop, using a methaphor:

> Mark was holding/tightening/squeezing the toy like if that was a raft
>   and he was adrift in the ocean.

Any seawolf out there :-) ?
thanks a lot!

Comment: What here is necessary? Must the word be specific for a child rather than for an adult? Or would a word that isn't limited by age work? Also, must it be for in a shop or can it be in a market or in a school room or anywhere at all? Also, must it be a metaphor itself or is the metaphor just a nice addition? Please edit your question to specify what is necessary and what is optional.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Holding on for dear life.**

> To hold something very tightly, as if one's life depended on it. The
>   hiker grabbed a root as she fell off the cliff, and had to hold on for
>   dear life while she waiting for the rescue crew. When the dentist
>   motioned us back into the examination room, my daughter clutched her
>   chair and held on for dear life.
>
> [[freedictionary]](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/holding+on+for+dear+life)

Comment: that looks a nice to hear expression! Thanks for sharing it!

Answer (score 5):

[Grasp](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grasp) is defined by the Oxford Online Dictionary as

> Seize and hold firmly.

Grasping is firmer, tighter and is associated with more emotion than 'holding'

The same dictionary defines [grip](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grip) as

> Take and keep a firm hold of; grasp tightly.

so gripping is, if anything, stronger and firmer than grasping since 'grip' is defined as 'grasp tightly'.

Either **grasping** or **gripping** would describe the child's action.

Answer (score 3):

**vice-like**

From https://www.thefreedictionary.com/vice-like

> vice (vaɪs) or vise n (Tools) an appliance for holding an object while
>   work is done upon it, usually having a pair of jaws vb (Mechanical
>   Engineering) (tr) to grip (something) with or as if with a vice [C15:
>   from Old French vis a screw, from Latin vītis vine, plant with
>   spiralling tendrils (hence the later meaning)] ˈviceˌlike, ˈviseˌlike
>   adj

Of course, the alternate meaning of "vice" (an undesirable habit) may add or detract from your sentence depending on context!

Answer (score 3):

**clinging (on) to**

This seems appropriate when talking about a child treating something as overly important, because it can also refer to an emotional dependence:

> 1 Hold on tightly to
>
> ...
>
> 1.4 Be overly dependent on (someone) emotionally.

( From https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cling)

Answer (score 1):

**clutching**

> 1. To grasp and hold tightly: *a child clutching a blanket.*

[[freedictionary]](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/clutching)